# What towers have special effect against ZOMGs?

Tags: bloons-td-5

The bomb tower has an upgrade that does 10 times more damage to MOAB class bloons (MOAB mauler). It's not clear how many hits from that will pop a ZOMG.

Also we have the Cripple MOAB upgrade for the sniper. Again, I do not know how many hits from that will pop a ZOMG.

Anything else?

Some say that a Dragon's Breath apprentices are good against it. If so, how? Does that do extra damage against ZOMGs? What?

Also, the Sun God may be good against ZOMGs, but why?

I notice that Rays of Doom are good against MOABs, but not that good against unclustered ZOMGs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, a fire mage has nothing that would allow it to be extra effective against ZOMG bloons, other than cleaning up after they've been destroyed. A Sun God is good against a ZOMG purely because of its raw damage output, but it does need assistance from other towers. The Sniper Monkey 4/2 temporarily stops a ZOMG from moving, as well as other blimp bloons.

Here are a few towers other towers that have special abilities against ZOMG:

An upgraded Bloonchipper (4/2) is able to suck in the ZOMG and then eject after sawing at it for a while.

A ninja monkey with the 'Sabotage Supply Lines' (2/4) ability is able to slow it significantly.

A Technological Terror (Super Monkey 2/4) has an AOE ability that deals 1000 damage to ZOMG bloons.

A Spike Factory (2/4) is designed to be effective against all blimp bloons, causing extra damage.

A Monkey Sub (2/4) has the First Strike Capabilty that destroys up to 1 ZOMG in one shot.

Comment: The thing with spike factory is that you want to put it in the bag while bloons are usually in the front. Also it's only 4 times as much.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this on easy after accumulating a tons of money with banana bank.

The key here is you use monkey temple.

How would you use it?

Well, you sacrifice 30k worth of cannon, 30k worth of ice, 30k worth of glue, 30k worth of wizard.

Some says you got to put some mortar too in exchange of some of the cannons. Make sure the upgrade of the sacrifices vary.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Now, the temples will shoot rockets. The rockets hit ZOMG really hard. In fact, at the end levels, (150+), those 4 temples are the only one remotely cost effective against ZOMG.

I played till level 150. Nothing else works.

I tested this in sandbox and one of this temple can destroy a whole 200 zomg send concurrently.

I've heard snipper can take out zomg in 20 hits. Don't know that. Without splash damage, they can't kill infinite numbers of zomg.

Comment: I agree with this about the monkey temple, but I assumed you meant individual towers, since monkey temple is only good when you sacrifice things to it.

Comment: Well it's the only thing cost effective. I mean at late stage, space is scarce so you can't put anything else. Also one such tower can destroy 200 zomg if sent too close to each other. So it's not just busting the zomg. It's the fact that it's doing it splash damage is what matters.

Comment: The Temple rockets don't hit harder than anything else (no MOAB bonus).  The reason why a Temple is effective against a ZOMG is the plasma ray.  A Temple's plasma ray can hit hard (up to two layers versus MOAB class bloons), deep (up to 160 targets), and as fast as anything in the game.

Comment: There are many videos and articles about how to make "max temples" online and on YouTube

Answer (score 2):

Bomb Tower - can be upgraded to a MOAB mauler to deal 10x damage to MOAB class bloons and the MOAB assassin ability that can seek out and destroy a MOAB.

Sniper Monkey - Its Cripple MOAB upgrade slows down MOAB class bloons.

Monkey Bucaneer - Monkey pirates gives it the ability to grapple and destroy a MOABs and BFBs (does not affect ZOMGs)

Bloonchipper -  The Super Wide Funnel upgrade allows it to suck up MOAB class bloons

Ninja Monkey - The Sabotage Supply Lines upgrade slows down all bloons to half speed for 15 seconds

Spike Factory - The MOAB SHREDR spikes makes it better against MOAB class bloons

Moab Assassin - Will do 1000 damage to ZOMGs, instantly destroying BFBs and MOABs, or the strongest bloon on the screen

Answer (score 2):

Towers which affect MOAB class bloons (including ZOMGs) differently than other bloons are:

1. Spike Factories with MOAB SHREDR spikes.  MOAB SHREDRs deal 4x damage to MOABs, and the Spike Storm spikes deal 3x damage.
2. MOAB Maulers (from the Bomb tower) do 10x damage to ZOMGs. ZOMGs have 4000 health, so you need 400 hits from MOAB Maulers to pop one.
3. Snipers with Cripple MOABs can stall ZOMGs.  The best method is to have one 4/2 sniper and one 4/0 sniper for max stalling, as their firing will be staggered.  It takes 223 hits from Cripple MOABs to pop a ZOMG.
4. One of the best methods for popping ZOMGs in BTD5 is the Bloonchipper upgraded to 4-0/4-2.  One of these will pop a ZOMG fully after sucking it in a few times (set it to strong so it only targets ZOMGs).
5. MOAB Assassins (also from the Bomb tower) do 1000 damage to ZOMGs with the ability, so you need four activations to destroy the ZOMG layer.
6. The monkey submarine will take out a ZOMG in one shot with the First Strike capability ability.
7. Temples with the Bomb sacrifice shoot MOAB Maulers which do extra damage to ZOMGs.  A max temple can defeat infinite ZOMGs.

However, the best way to take down a ZOMG is not just one super damage tower, but a combination.  For example, you may want to use a Sabotage Supply Lines ninja to slow it to 1/2 speed (and on mobile and Absolute Zero ice tower to slow it down to 1/2 of that).  Spike Factories are good MOAB popping power, but you should have an Ice Tower upgraded to Arctic wind to pop the remaining Bloons.  MOAB Maulers aren't very effective against ZOMGs.

Comment: Also in Battles, the Phoenix does extra damage to ZOMGs, and Bloonchippers cannot damage ZOMGs at all.

Answer (score 0):

A Spike Storm can pop MOAB,BFB,ZOMG if it is used 52 times and has white hot spikes upgraded or 100 times